# ACE Editor turn off all Auto Completions and Expansions

Tags: ace-editor

Is there a way in ACE editor to turn off all completions for a given syntax Mode, but still display all the appropriate syntax coloring for the syntax?

For example: In **markdown** mode is there a way to not expand things like `"` and `[` to complete the second quote/bracket, or bullet lists to the next line.

I know there are a few individual settings that do this like `mode.$quotes` and `mode.getNextLineIndent` but there are many others that are not easily tracked in one place.

Is there a switch to universally turn off all expansions of any kind?

Tried the following options settings with no luck:

```js
te.editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/" + lang);
          
te.editor.setOptions({
            enableAutoIndent: false,
            behaviorsEnabled: false,
            enableBasicAutocompletion: false,
            enableLiveAutocompletion: false,
            enableSnippets: false
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest thing is

```
editor.setOptions({enableAutoIndent: false, behavioursEnabled: false})
```

---

*Looks like `behavioursEnabled` is the key to disabling quotes and bracket expansion*

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work for markdown autocompletions like `"` or `[` or `(` :-( Also added these: `enableLiveAutocompletion`, `enableLiveAutocompletion` and  `enableSnippets`  setting all to `false` with no luck.Updated post to reflect. Thanks.

Comment: Which version of ace are you using? On https://ace.c9.io/ if i run `editor.setOptions({ mode: "ace/mode/markdown"})` to set markdown mode, and run the snippet above, all completions are disabled.

Comment: I'm on 1.4.12. It may be that some expansions are disabled, but are quote and bracket expansions disabled when you use the code above?

Comment: Ok - thank you for your patience @a_user. Looking at my code I just noticed I have `behaviorsEnabled` instead of `behavioursEnabled`. Once I fixed that the quote and bracket expansion stops. So it looks like `enableBehaviors` is the key for those operations. Brits...LOL. Thank you!